# canvas.drawBitmap gives two different results

Tags: android, android-canvas

I m taking screenshot of android screen and Draw another image on captured image (watermark) using canvas.drawBitmap,

it all giving proper result when i copy the Watermark(another image - say visit.jpg) image on SD card, **the captured image has width 500pixel, where visit.jpg has width- 339pixels,**

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/visit.jpg");
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

but i dont want to copy the watermark image into sdcard, i want the image from res folder should get draw on captured image, so i used

```
Bitmap visit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.visit);
```

and draw on canvas and saved, it get saved, but the Watermark image(visit.jpg) gets stretch and its size gets larger than 339pixels. why ?

my code is :

```
        View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

        Bitmap cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenshot, 50, 0, screenshot.getWidth()-100, 592);
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


        Bitmap Rbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropimg).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);


        Bitmap visit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.visit); // image accessed from drawable
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Rbitmap);       

        File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/visit.jpg"); // the image copied on sd card
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        canvas.drawBitmap(visit, 0, 570, null); // if i put myBitmap instead of visit i.e.  canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 570, null); then visit.jpg image gets draw properly with 339pixel width without strtch
        canvas.save();
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on the topic but you could try using ``BitmapFactory.decodeResource(..., BitmapFactory.Options)`` where you make sure that ``Options.inScaled`` is set to false.

Comment: Try `visit.getWidth()` and `visit.getHeight()`, to see if the bitmap is stretched or if it happens later.

Comment: visit.jpg is 339x22,but visit.getWidth() shows 452 and visit.getHeight() shows 29, why ?

Comment: That is somehow strange. I tried to reproduce your situation by quickly prototyping a similar app. The watermark appears OK on my side, without stretch. Link: http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/4971/savedimage.jpg (Penguins is the watermark)

Comment: @AndyRes , which one you tried the File-Bitmap or BitmapFactory ? as i mentioned using File-Bitmap, is giving proper result.

Comment: Both, and no difference. The screenshot is with the watermark from drawable resource.

Comment: Every other image i tried to put is also became same-stretch, the width and height of the picture gets larger than original size.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I forgot an easier way, put the images in /res/drawable-nodpi folder.

Android will automatically scale the resource image depending on your screen density. The default drawable folder correspond to the mdpi so if you have a hdpi device the image will be scaled up. You can put the image into the /res/raw/ folder then open it like:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.app.package/raw/visit");
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
```